# Which real random law maximize the standard deviation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization

Which random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ has the maximal standard deviation for the two following cases:

1. $\Omega$ is descrete and, let's $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $|\Omega|=n$
2. $\Omega$ is $[0;1]$

I believe standard deviation $\sigma$ of random variable $X$ is $\sigma(X) = \sqrt{\mathbb E[X²]-\mathbb E[X]^2}$. So our problem would be to find

$$\displaystyle\arg \max_{X\in \mathbb R^\Omega} \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2$$

How should I continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 does not give a meaningful optimization problem since virtually any random variable can be defined on the unit interval. You can let $U$ be the identity map on $\left[0,1\right]$ with $P$ being the Lebesgue measure. Then $U \sim U\left[0,1\right]$, and you can create any random variable $X$ with cdf $F$ by taking $X = F^{-1}\left(U\right)$. In this way you can create continuous random variables with infinite variance (Pareto) or undefined variance (Cauchy).

If what you mean is that the random variable must have bounded *support*, then the variance is maximized by assigning equal probability to the lower and upper bounds. It is well-known that, if $0 \leq X\left(\omega\right) \leq a$ for all $\omega$, then $Var\left(X\right) \leq \frac{a^2}{4}$, and the bound is attained with equality when $P\left(X=0\right)=P\left(X=a\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.